# Error in Web Services java (jsp) StandardWrapperValve[]:... threw exception java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: web-services, jsp, servlets, weka, glassfish-4

I'm developing the web service and in it weka use, weka query the data stored in the database (sql server 2008), to generate clustering models, from the weka gui takes in creating the models 19 minutes and there does not occur any Problem , But when I try in the test netbeans call the service that performs this , happens the following error.

Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[NameWS]: Servlet.service() for servlet NameWS threw exception
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)

Can anybody help me please

Grave:   Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[ModuloIntegenciaNegociosWS]: Servlet.service() for servlet ModuloIntegenciaNegociosWS threw exception
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:477)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.writeCompositeBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleWrite(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleWrite(TransportFilter.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:858)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1029)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBinaryBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:1016)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushAllBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:987)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:175)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:225)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:259)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.flush(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:403)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:636)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:878)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Can u attach full stack trace?

Comment: Hi, of course, I edited the question and i added  the full stack trace, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Grave: Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver - Advertencia:
```

I think you didn't specify classpath.
Add SQLServer dependency and add the name of this driver to your dataSource connection. 
How to add look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/540489/8041441)

Comment: Thanks, finally that is the mistake. Because I did not configure the weka jar for the database I was using. Thank you very much :)